# EST to UTC conversion in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that will convert any date and time in EST to a UTC timestamp (I do not mean the current timestamp, but rather a specific date and time).

The function must take into account the DST (Daylight Savings Time) for that given date.

I have tinkered with gmdate with no results.

The result should look like this:
20060415T180000Z    (180000 being 6pm and 00 seconds)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Though this won't fully answer the question, maybe this will help.
As I am aware, there are two rules for Daylight Saving Time (DST) in the Eastern
  Standard Time zone:

- For 2006 and earlier, DST begins at 2 A.M. on the first Sunday of April and 
  ends at 2 A.M. on the last Sunday of October.
- For 2007 and later, DST begins at 2 A.M. on the second Sunday of March and 
  ends at 2 A.M. on the first Sunday of November.

Unless you're dealing with very old dates, you should be fine with the above rules.